# wlan Loopback throughput via usb is only 273 Mbps when bus speed is 480 Mbps

Tags: android, linux, usb, wifi

I have a STB 7445 device to which our wlan chip is connected via usb.

After loading driver and firmware for wlan0 interface, IP address is assigned to wlan0 interface.

IP Address:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.2
```

Thereafter I am running loopback throughput test on a dummy address added in arp entry.

ARP Entry:

```
# /system/xbin/busybox/arp -s 192.168.1.4 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Run iperf to measure UDP TPUT:

```
# iperf -c 192.168.1.4 -i1 -w2M -b1000M -t 60
.
.
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  32.5 MBytes    273 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 59.0-60.0 sec  32.5 MBytes    273 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-60.0 sec  1.90 GBytes    273 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 1390851 datagrams
[  3] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43569a2 #
```

I am getting throughput of only 273 Mbps, whereas the bus speed is 480 Mbps.

usb bus speed:

```
#cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/speed
480
```

Comment: You are measuring udp thoughput. Not bus speed.

Comment: Isnt the udp throughput dependent on bus speed? Anyway, if you have any pointers could you help resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes they depend. I suggest you do the same test with other computers and devices. Then compare.

Answer (score 1):

The ip stack will notice that the destination is the same machine, so no packets are sent out to the hardware. You are just measureing the software performance of the linux IP stack, and your CPU is a bit slow.

USB 2.0 high speed is 480 MBit/s, but it cannot send and receive at the same time. That means if you send packets to hardware and receive them again, you cannot exeed 240 MBit/s - in practice even lower since there will be some overhead.

Comment: Is there any other way to test loopback throughput?